# Como compilar um projeto Java 9 com Lombok no Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, java-9, lombok

## TL;DR

> Como passar vários parâmetros `-J--add-opens=<pacote>=ALL-UNNAMED` para que o Gradle os utilize ao invocar o `javac`?

## Detalhes

Tenho um código *HelloWorld.java* usando o [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) no Java 9:

```
import lombok.NonNull;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(@NonNull String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

A versão do Lombok é a versão instável [edge](https://projectlombok.org/download-edge) (esse link pode mudar no futuro, trata-se de uma versão 1.16.19). Coloquei o *lombok-edge.jar* na mesma pasta do *HelloWorld.java* acima.

O Lombok ainda não está maduro o suficiente para ser usado no Java 9 devido às inúmeras dificuldades que a modularização do Java 9 introduziu. Entretanto, dá para compilar e rodar ele mesmo assim com os devidos abusos na linha de comando:

```
javac -parameters -Xlint:all,-processing --add-modules=java.xml.ws.annotation -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED -cp lombok-edge.jar HelloWorld.java
```

Com isso, nenhuma *warning* aparece e o arquivo *HelloWorld.class* é gerado. E então:

```
java HelloWorld
```

Produz essa saída:

```
Hello World
```

Até aqui, tudo muito bem, mas agora eu queria fazer isso no Gradle.

Tentei com esse arquivo:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.9'

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'HelloWorld'
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly files('libs/lombok-edge.jar')
    testCompileOnly files('libs/lombok-edge.jar')
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.compilerArgs << "-parameters" << "-Xlint:all,-processing"
    options.compilerArgs << "--add-modules=java.xml.ws.annotation"
    options.compilerArgs << "-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED"
    options.compilerArgs << "-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED"
    options.compilerArgs << "-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED"
    options.compilerArgs << "-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED"
    options.compilerArgs << "-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED"
    options.compilerArgs << "-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED"
    options.compilerArgs << "-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED"
    options.compilerArgs << "-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED"
    options.compilerArgs << "-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED"
}
```

Obviamente, coloquei o *lombok-edge.jar* dentro de uma pasta *libs*.

Ao tentar dar o *build* com o Gradle 4.2:

```
gradle build
```

O resultado foi isso:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> invalid flag: -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Uma vez que a compilação por linha de comando funciona, esse não deve ser um problema no Lombok (o problema com ele é precisar dessa absurda e esotérica quantidade de parâmetros de linha de comando para funcionar no Java 9). Acredito que o problema esteja simplesmente no fato de eu não saber usar direito o Gradle, um problema que se reduz simplesmente a:

> Como passar vários parâmetros `-J--add-opens=<pacote>=ALL-UNNAMED` para que o Gradle os utilize ao invocar o `javac`?

Editado: Tentei também com o Gradle 4.3.1, e o resultado foi ainda pior que o do Gradle 4.2:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.reflect.SourcepathIgnoringInvocationHandler (file:/C:/Users/d841156/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.3.1-bin/7yzdu24db77gi3zukl2a7o0xx/gradle-4.3.1/lib/plugins/gradle-language-java-4.3.1.jar) to method com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileManager.handleOption(java.lang.String,java.util.Iterator)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.reflect.SourcepathIgnoringInvocationHandler
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> invalid flag: -J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    compileOnly files("libs/lombok-edge.jar")
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { 
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += [
          '--add-opens', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED',
          '--add-opens', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED',
          '--add-opens', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED',
          '--add-opens', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED',
          '--add-opens', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED',
          '--add-opens', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED',
          '--add-opens', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED',
          '--add-opens', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED',
          '--add-opens', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED'
        ]
}
```

Conforme [esse comentário](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1472#issuecomment-343969972) no GitHub essa combinação está funcionando com `lombok-edge`, Gradle 4.2.1 e Java 9. O autor do comentário inclusive afirma ter conseguido uma *build* limpa com o plugin `java-library` mesmo após comentar as `forkOptions`.